# upload photo code for facebook iframe tab

Tags: facebook, upload, facebook-iframe

we are trying to add an upload image button on our facebook iframe tab. When user clicks button it will pop up an upload photo box. Which then the photo would be inserted into a photo gallery.  I have seen this done but do not know how to do it.